# Vagrant and git bash

Tags: git, virtualbox, vagrant, git-bash

I like to use git bash instead of windows command prompt.

I've just installed vagrant and Vbox.

When I vagrant init in git bash I get

`d:\Program Files\Vagrant\embedded\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- d:/
Program/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb (LoadError)`

When I call the command in command prompt it works, I'm trying to tear myself away from guis im quite new to CLIs

anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I uninstalled vagrant, renamed C:\Users\%USER%\.vagrant.d to .vagrant.d.bak, and then reinstalled. That seems to have solved the issue.