# Using GitBash packaged with Atlassian, SourceTree "Vagrant Up" doesn't work

Tags: git, bash, vagrant

Hey guys I did a new machine setup on my laptop, installed VirtualBox and Vagrant running Laravel Framework projects.

Issue I have is the following:

Git Bash doesn't recognize vagrant at all, if I do vagrant anything nothing happens.

However if I run CMD Prompt I am able to use Vagrant globally and do vagrant up which works fine.

I am wondering why am I unable to do it with GitBash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching to "Git system" (ie the one you can install on your Windows) instead of relying on "Git embedded".

Make sure you are launching SourceTree from a Windows session (or Windows CMD) where your PATH does include your Git installation, as extracted from the [latest Git releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), like [PortableGit-2.13.3-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.13.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.13.3-64-bit.7z.exe).

See an [example of such PATH here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44878018/6309).

```
set GH=C:\Git2.13.3
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Launch SourceTree from there.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try, I am just about to head out of the house... If it works I will make sure to accept the answer thank you for your time!

Comment: Same issue still.. My Git-CMD can run Vagrant Up with no issue but GitBash can't

Comment: @IamCavic "I do vagrant anything nothing happens." no output at all? no error message? nothing in any vagrant log?

Comment: @IamCavic Maybe something is wrong in the .vagrant.d folder? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22587936/6309)

Comment: No I tried it all including a uninstall - install, when I run in GitBash Vagrant (anything) it just goes to the new line it gives no warning or errors just nothing happens

Comment: @IamCavic like stdout/stderr were redirected somewhere. What does `which vagrant` return?

Comment: PortableGit works but Git doesn't... wired thanks for help I will just use the one you have recommended in the first place

Comment: this is what is returned on the other one but it doesn't work $ which vagrant
/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant

Comment: @IamCavic Yes, I never use the Git setup, always the portable one: I have a better control over the PATH that way.